# How to obtain the task_id from the rds_restore_database stored procedure using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I need to execute the **rds_restore_database** stored procedure from my own procedure, so I need to get the task_id just after execution to execute **rds_task_status** for awaiting the restoring is SUCCESS.

I don't know how to get the task_id in a variable after restoring:

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database 'whatever', 'S3_bucket_bak'
```

and I don't know how to get the lifecycle column in other variable to check restoring status:

```
exec [msdb].[dbo].[rds_task_status] @task_id=@mytaskid
```

The only approach I tried is to insert into a temp table the result:

```
INSERT INTO #MyTempTable exec @task_id = msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database 'whatever', 'S3_bucket_bak'
```

But I have to drop and insert again whenever I want to check how is the restoring status.

There is any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

The best workaround i've been able to find:

```
declare @my_task_id int
select top 1 @my_task_id = task_id from msdb.dbo.rds_fn_task_status(NULL,0) order by task_id desc
select @my_task_id task_id
```

Or, if what you want to do is the same as I, to halt code execution until all tasks are done, the following should work:

```
declare @sec int = 0;
WHILE ((SELECT top 1 lifecycle FROM msdb.dbo.rds_fn_task_status(NULL,0) order by task_id desc) <> 'SUCCESS')
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';
    set @sec = @sec + 10
    if @sec >= 1800 RAISERROR ('Timout. Copying from S3 to RDS server took more than 30 minutes.',16,1)
END
```

It'd be a ton better if the stored procedures created by the rds team would just return the task_id. But they don't, so..

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware of the table function rds_fn_task_status so thanks to Tor for that.  However I have a couple of slight issues with the above answer, namely: It relies on no other tasks being initiated on your RDS instance whilst it's running (so for instance we run multiple databases on a single instance and this script as is would cause us problems).  Also if your task errors you're going to be waiting the entire timeout period and still not receive an indication it errored (just that it timed out).

So with that would like to propose a slight modification:

```
declare @sec int = 0;
declare @taskId int
declare @lifecycle nvarchar(50)
select @taskId = max(task_id) FROM msdb.dbo.rds_fn_task_status(NULL,0)
set @lifecycle = ''

WHILE @lifecycle NOT IN ('SUCCESS', 'ERROR')
BEGIN
    SELECT @lifecycle = lifecycle FROM msdb.dbo.rds_fn_task_status(NULL,@taskId)
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';
    set @sec = @sec + 10
    if @sec >= 1800 RAISERROR ('Timout. Copying from S3 to RDS server took more than 30 minutes.',16,1)
END

if @lifeCycle <> 'SUCCESS' 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @taskAsStr nvarchar(50)
    SET @taskAsStr = CAST(@taskId as nvarchar(50))
    RAISERROR (N'Error. Copying from S3 to RDS server raised an unexpected error for task %s',16,1, @taskAsStr)
END
```